# How to create inverse border radius?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

How to achieve this type of text highlighting using CSS?

[image]

This is my result and the code below combining CSS and vuetify.

[image]

```
<div>
  <div class="tittle-font pt-4 rounded-t-xl ">
    SOFTWARE
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="tittle-font rounded-tr-xl ">
    DEVELOPMENT
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="tittle-font pb-4 rounded-b-xl rounded-tr-xl">
    AND CONSULTING
  </div>
</div>

.tittle-font {
    font-size: calc(34px + (36 + 36 * 0.7) * ((100vw - 320px) / 1920));
    line-height: calc(46px + (65 + 65 * 0.7) * ((100vw - 320px) / 1920));
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: #fff500;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use after and before pseudo elements.

First of all our boxes will have `position:relative` and our pseudo elements need to have `position:absolute`

I create a circle and make it tangent to borders with `::after`

[image]

Than i create another square and put it into corner which have lower `z-index` and have `overflow:hidden`

`z-index` is important here because when we set background color of circle to body color(which is white here), circle will disappear and the only thing left is `::before` element which seems to have inverse border radius

[image]

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.tittle-font {
  position: relative;
  font-size: calc(34px + (36 + 36 * 0.7) * ((100vw - 320px) / 1920));
  line-height: calc(46px + (65 + 65 * 0.7) * ((100vw - 320px) / 1920));
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #fff500;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.box-1{
  
  border-top-left-radius:1rem ;
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}
.box-2{
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}

.box-3{
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}

.box-1::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: white;
  z-index:5;
  right: -2rem;
  bottom:0rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.box-1::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff500;
  z-index:4;
  right: -1rem;
  bottom:0rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-2::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: white;
  z-index:5;
  right: -2rem;
  bottom:0rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.box-2::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff500;
  z-index:4;
  right: -1rem;
  bottom:0rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <div>
      <div class="tittle-font pt-4 box-1 rounded-t-xl">SOFTWARE</div>
      <br />
      <div class="tittle-font rounded-tr-xl box-2">DEVELOPMENT</div>
      <br />
      <div class="tittle-font pb-4 rounded-b-xl rounded-tr-xl box-3">
        AND CONSULTING
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way and of course you can add padding, border-radius or any styling you need. hope this help <3

```css
span{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    width: fit-content;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>some heighlighted text here.</span> with simple way
</div>
```